# Extending of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n+\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$

Tags: real-analysis

We know that if $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ as $n\to \infty$ then $a_n+b_n\to a+b$ as $n\to \infty$. It's quite easy to prove.

But what if we take two divergent sequences? Namely, $a_n=n$ and $b_n=-n$ then $a_n\to +\infty$ and $b_n\to -\infty$ but $a_n+b_n\to 0$. If we make convention that $\infty+(-\infty)=(-\infty)+\infty=0$ then I guess that everything will be OK and we can extend the rule $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n+\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_n$, right?

If I am wrong please clarify my thoughts.

Would be very gtareful for any help.

Comment: That would imply $n^2 -n\to 0$

Comment: If all you know is  $a_n\to\infty$ and $b_n\to-\infty$ then there is nothing you can say about the sequence $a_n+b_n$.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is a problem here. Take the example $a_n=n^2$ and $b_n=-n$. We have $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to -\infty$, but the limit of $a_n+b_n$ is still $\infty$.

Another example: $L$ is a real number, $a_n=n+L$, $b_n=-n$. Then $a_n+b_n \to L$.

So because of that reasons the expression $\infty+(-\infty)$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, we cannot determine the $\infty-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$\infty-\infty$ is a so-called indeterminate form. There are several of these, other examples include $0\cdot\infty$ and $1^\infty$ (meaning the limits of $a_n\cdot b_n$ and $a_n^{b_n}$ respectively, where $a_n$ and $b_n$ have the limits hinted at by the forms).

These are called indeterminate precisely because you can't tell at all what the limit is just from the limit of $a_n$ and $b_n$ (although for $1^\infty$ you can tell that the answer, if it exists, is at least $1$). It isn't very difficult to come up with examples. For instance, for $\infty-\infty$, we have $$n^2-n\to\infty\\n-n^2\to-\infty\\n-(n-c)\to c$$where $c$ is any real number constant.

Comment: Thank you, Arthur! Right now I understood the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The limiting form $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate. What happens here is a tug of war, so to speak. Perhaps the first term dominates, leading to $\infty$. Perhaps the latter term drives the limit to $-\infty$. Or, perhaps there is a compromise, and the limit is some $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$. We need to know the rate at which the limiting sequences diverge to assess the outcome.